# what is Difference between eav attribute_model, source_model, backend_model, frontend_model

Tags: magento2

can anyone explain uses of this model

Answer (score 1):

Actually is pretty easy.

source_model usually is used in select and multiselect input types.
You can create the class where will return the options of the select/multiselect.

frontend_model is a class that you create so you can manipulate your attribute on frontend, like classes, label (prefixes...), visibility, options nd etc. A really good way to understand better this is looking the function of the abstract class.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Frontend/AbstractFrontend.php

backend_model is a class that you create so you can manipulate your attribute on backend, like validations. A really good way to understand better this is also looking the function of the abstract class.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/AbstractBackend.php

These abstract classes, you should always extend them and use them in your favor, calling the function you want and do what you got to do.